# "Noetherian" and "finitely generated" for polynomial algebras

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, nonnoetherian, noetherian

Let $k$ be a field. Does there exist a positive integer $n$ such that there is $k$-subalgebra of $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ which is Noetherian but not finitely generated?

Comment: If $A \subset k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is a graded subalgebra then a standard fact is that Noetherian implies finitely generated: a system of generators is obtained by taking generators of the ideal $I = A \cap k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]_{\geq 1}$ (polynomials with no constant term). I don't know about the general case.

Comment: Meta discussion here:  https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4200/flood-of-new-users

Answer (score 15):

The following example of Eakin [Eak72] says that $n = 2$ already suffices. I have tried to fill in some details to (hopefully) make the example independent from the rest of Eakin's paper.

**Example** [Eak72, Example on p. 79]**.** Let $k$ be a field, and consider the formal power series ring $k[[t]]$ in one variable over $k$. By an argument of Schmidt (see [Sch33, Hilfssatz 5] or [MLS39, Second Proof of Lemma 1]), there exist two algebraically independent elements $x,y \in k[[t]]$ that have the same positive valuation with respect to the valuation on $k[[t]]$. For a specific example, Schmidt's result implies that one can choose
$$x = t \qquad\text{and}\qquad y = \sum_{n=1}^\infty t^{n!}.$$
Now let $V = k[[t]] \cap k(x,y)$ and $R = k[x,1/y] \cap V$. Setting $X = x$ and $Y = 1/y$, we have
$$k \subseteq k[X,XY] \subseteq R \subseteq k[X,Y].$$
We then show the following:

*Claim.* $R$ is noetherian but not finitely generated as a $k$-algebra.

To show that $R$ is noetherian, we note that $R$ is a Krull ring by [Mat89, Theorem 12.4(ii)] since both $k[x,1/y]$ and $V$ are Krull. A theorem of Heinzer [Hei69, Theorem 9] (see also [Eak72, footnote 1 on p. 78]) then implies that $R$ is noetherian.

To show that $R$ is not finitely generated as a $k$-algebra, we first note that the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{m}_V \cap R$ has height one in $R$ and that $V = R_{\mathfrak{p}}$, since $V$ is a DVR that must appear when $R$ is written as the intersection of DVR's in $k(X,Y)$ [Mat89, Theorem 12.3]. The residue field of $V$ is $k$, since it must simultaneously contain $k$ and also be contained in the residue field of $k[[t]]$, which is $k$. Thus, $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of height one in $R$ whose residue field is not transcendental over $k$, which cannot be the case if $R$ is finitely generated over $k$ [ZS75, Corollary on p. 92].

#### References

[Eak72] Paul Eakin. "A note on finite dimensional subrings of polynomial rings."
*Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* **31** (1972), 75–80. DOI: [10.2307/2038515](https://doi.org/10.2307/2038515). MR: [289498](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=289498).

[Hei69] William Heinzer. "On Krull overrings of a Noetherian domain." *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* **22** (1969), 217–222. DOI: [10.2307/2036956](https://doi.org/10.2307/2036956). MR: [254022](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=254022).

[Mat89] Hideyuki Matsumura. *Commutative ring theory.* Second ed. Translated from the Japanese by M. Reid. Cambridge Stud. Adv. Math. 8. Cambridge Univ. Press, Cambridge, 1989. DOI: [10.1017/CBO9781139171762](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139171762). MR: [1011461](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1011461).

[MLS39] Saunders Mac Lane and O. F. G. Schilling. "Zero-dimensional branches of rank one on algebraic varieties." *Ann. of Math. (2)* **40**, (1939), 507–520. DOI: [10.2307/1968935](https://doi.org/10.2307/1968935). MR: [158](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=158).

[Sch33] Friedrich Karl Schmidt. "Mehrfach perfekte Körper." *Math. Ann.* **108** (1933), no. 1, 1–25. DOI: [10.1007/BF01452819](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01452819). MR: [1512831](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1512831).

[ZS75] Oscar Zariski and Pierre Samuel. *Commutative algebra. Vol. II.* Reprint of the 1960 edition. Grad. Texts in Math. 29. Springer-Verlag, New York-Heidelberg, 1975. DOI: [10.1007/978-3-662-29244-0](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-29244-0). MR: [389876](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=389876).